# Why if i enqueue the tinymce script i get undefined error

Tags: plugin-development, tinymce

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: random plug
Plugin URI: http://example.com/wordpress-plugins/my-plugin
Description: A plugin demonstrating Cron in WordPress
Version: 1.0
Author: Brad Williams
Author URI: http://wrox.com
License: GPLv2
*/

add_action('init', 'register_tagging_post');

 function register_tagging_post(){
       $tagging_args = array(
           'public' => true,
           'supports' => array(
               'title',
               'thumbnail'

           ), 
           'query_var' => 'tagging',
           'rewrite' => array(
              'slug' => 'tagging',
              'with_front' => false
           ),
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Tagge Albums',
            'singular_name' => 'Album',
            'add_new' => 'Add New Album',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Album',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Album',
            'new_item' => 'New Album',
            'view_item' => 'View Album',
            'search_items' => 'Search Albums',
            'not_found' => 'No Albums Found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Albums Found In Trash'
        ),

       );

       register_post_type('tagging', $tagging_args);

        wp_enqueue_script('tinymce123','http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js');


 }

?>
```

This is my plugin created, I want to ask why the firebug produced an error:

```
TypeError: tinymce.onAddEditor is undefined
```

when i enqueue the tinymce script and it is not functioning?

Comment: Why do you need to enqueue TinyMCE from external site? Where exactly error originates from?

Comment: When you view the page source, do you find your TinyMCE included? Try using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook instead.